# repository design pattern identitydbcontext problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, repository-pattern, repository-design, crud-repository

I get the following error with the repository design pattern. I get this error from EfEntityRepositoryBase while inheriting EfCarDal in the Data Access layer. I couldn't overcome the problem.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0311  The type 'Carebook.Dal.Concrete.EntityFramework.Conetext.AppDbContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method
> 'EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Carebook.Dal.Concrete.EntityFramework.Conetext.AppDbContext' to
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext`

---

```
namespace Carebook.Core.DataAccess.Concrete
{
    public class EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext> : IEntityRepository<TEntity>, IDisposable
        where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
        where TContext : IdentityDbContext, new()

    {
        public void Add(TEntity entity)
        {
            using (TContext context = new TContext())
            {
                var addEntity = context.Entry(entity);
                addEntity.State = EntityState.Added;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public void Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            using (TContext context = new TContext())
            {
                var deleteEntity = context.Entry(entity);
                deleteEntity.State = EntityState.Deleted;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>? filter)
        {
            using (TContext context = new TContext())
            {
                return context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(filter);
            }
        }

        public List<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>? filter = null)
        {
            using (TContext context = new TContext())
            {
                return filter == null ?
                    context.Set<TEntity>().ToList() :
                    context.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter).ToList();

            }
        }

        public void Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            using (TContext context = new TContext())
            {
                var updateEntity = context.Entry(entity);
                updateEntity.State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}

 namespace Carebook.Dal.Concrete.EntityFramework.Conetext
{
    public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>
    {


        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
          : base(options)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<CarPicture> CarPictures { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Feature> Features { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Pricing> Pricings { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
}
  
namespace Carebook.Dal.Concrete.EntityFramework
{
    public class EfCareDal: EfEntityRepositoryBase<Car,AppDbContext>,ICarDal
    {


    }
}
```

Comment: How we can help here? We also can lok at error message and write text which is reprasing the same error message. Error message is clear enough: `IdentityDbContext` is not derived from `AppDbContext`, which is required in `EfEntityRepositoryBase` generic parameters constraints.

Comment: Share `EfEntityRepositoryBase` definition.

Comment: Any reason for using the repository pattern on top of entity framework? The `DbContext` already implements the `Repo/UoW` patterns.

Comment: I posted it below, I could not find any documentation on the use of identitydbcontext in warehouse design.

Comment: The codes I added do not fit the identitydbcontext warehouse design, how can we make it fit?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error saying that `AppDbContext` cannot be used as the `TContext` type parameter in the generic class `EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext>`. The reason for this error is that the constraints on `TContext` expect it to inherit from `IdentityDbContext`, but as specified, it should inherit without any generic type parameters.

In your code you have set the `AppDbContext` inherit from `IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>` to resolve that you have to make sure `EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext>` can work with `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey>` instead of the non-generic `IdentityDbContext`.

Below is the sample code you try:

```
public class EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext> : IEntityRepository<TEntity>, IDisposable
    where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
    where TContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>, new() 
{
    // Your original code
}
```